# InnerHtml in WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net

I need help with `InnerHtml`.

[image]

How can I know when one of these change color to green? It needs to be specific. Not `WebBrowser1.document.body.innertext.contains("Green")`

So something like:

```
If WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("data-search_id ="1740").InnerText.Contains("background-color: Green;") Then
    Label1.Text = ("Working")
End if
```

This wont work because `data-search_id ="1740"` isn't an id. I think it needs to be something like InnerHtml `data-search_id ="1740"` and `InnerText.contains`, or something like that.

(This is how it looks when its green: `background-color: Green;`)

I've tried several things. Example:

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
    If webpageelement.GetAttribute("data-search_id") = "1762".Contains("background-color: green;") Then
         Label1.Text = "Working"
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tr")

        For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements
            Dim SearchID = webpageelement.GetAttribute("data-search_id")
            Dim Style As String = ""

            If webpageelement.Style IsNot Nothing Then
                Style = webpageelement.Style
            End If

            If SearchID = "1762" AndAlso Style.Contains("green") Then
                Label1.Text = "Working"
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply.

As far as i can see this wont work. Because if search id is 1762 (which it is) AndAlso Style.Contains("green") what if id 1740 gets green? that would still trigger it since search id 1762 is still there. wouldnt it? I cant test this right now since it isnt green yet..

Comment: No, this loops through each table row in the for loop.  So, it will only trigger where the ID is 1762 and that row's style contains green.